# Permutation Distribution in r

Tags: r, statistics, permutation, distribution

So I need to create a permutation distribution of the difference in the proportions for a data set, however I'm not sure the best way to go about doing so.

This is the table that I need it for. I have to asses whether the difference between 2010 and 2011 is significant for "Yes".

```
mytable1 <- matrix(c(3648,25843,3407,26134), byrow=T, ncol=2)
dimnames(mytable1) <- list(c("2010","2011"),c("Yes","No"))
names(dimnames(mytable1)) <- c("Year","Response")
```

How do I code this in a for-loop?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Why use a permutation-based test if you can calculate [exact probabilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_exact_test)? Is this a homework exercise?

```
fisher.test(mytable1);

    Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data

data:  mytable1
p-value = 0.001799
alternative hypothesis: true odds ratio is not equal to 1
95 percent confidence interval:
 1.029882 1.138384
sample estimates:
odds ratio
  1.082775
```

gives you the *exact* probabilitity (the p-value) for seeing a ratio of "Yes" to "No" in 2010 relative to 2011 (i.e. the odds ratio) *as extreme or more  extreme* than what was observed. Note that the null hypothesis corresponds to an odds ratio of 1.

I assume this is what you mean by the "difference between 2010 and 2011 is significant [for Yes]". If not, please clarify and be more precise in specifying your test statistic (and null hypothesis). If it needs to be a permutation-based test, can you show us how far you have gotten?